# Connect "islands" for 3d printed models

Tags: add-on, 3d-printing

I am working on several models for cases, for home automation and electronics components, including raspberry pi and esp32 boards.

I realise there are many models online but need to make bespoke cases.

The issue I have is that I don't know if there is a simple way to connect elements of cutouts in a print model so that the model retains integrity and the cutout looks decent. An example is the raspberry pi logo I have cut out of one such case (pictured). As it is, it is clear that many elements of the cutout are not connected physically to the case so these "islands" need some form of small struts to hold them together. Is there a smart way of doing this whereby the struts are small enough to not spoil the aesthetics too much but strong enough to keep the case and logo intact when printing? An addon maybe? I want to do a few of these, not just the Rasp Pi.

[image: Raspberry pi cutout]

Answer (score 0):

Some options.

1. You may need to change the orientation of the print, so that the symbol is printing on the bottom.
2. Design your own 3D supports within the model (this is what I do for various holes / openings that are needed)
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upqTE8EPZIQ
3. Also make use of the 3D printing add-on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rgrLWFUjlk
4. You can emboss / engrave it (you may need to convert it to an svg)

**SVG to FONT:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278707/how-can-i-convert-svg-files-to-a-font

**Emboss / Engrave:**

https://youtu.be/lc3d0pM2fpo

5. You may also want to try it with Geometry Nodes.
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srmzM2cWW7U

I do all my 3D printing designs using Blender and I find it works very well once you get the hang of it.

A good how to when FDM printing:  (the best idea I got from this series was to angle things at 45 degrees)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvpDgC7g68o&list=PL80oNe5cvR7886KeFH5YNhE0Io7YYgEIi